# How can I install a real time kernel?

Tags: 10.10, kernel, ppa, ubuntu-studio

Is there a repository I can use to install `linux-rt` for Ubuntu 10.10? This package used to be available from the default repositories but isn't in the 10.10 repositories.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find the news that the project, do to lack of support has gone to sleep for a while: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RealTime

At least as it looks it is going to come back on 11.04